# Meteor method inserting two records... only sometimes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, meteor

I have a simple meteor application that uses mongo and the google maps API to show stored locations on a map. There is a button that calls an insert method to insert the location into the database, however sometimes it will insert the same location twice. I have had this issue sporadically across multiple devices which has made it hard to troubleshoot or identify the root of the problem.

The method in question:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'markers.insert'(position) {

      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }
      console.log("Marker location received for insert.");
        Markers.insert({
          position: position,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          owner: Meteor.userId(),
          username: Meteor.user().profile.name,
        });
    },
    ...
```

The code that calls the method:

```
Template.MapPage.events({
        'click .needle-btn': ()=> {
            if (Position == null) {
              alert("Location services not enabled :(")
            }

            if (Meteor.userId() != null) {
              console.log("inserting");
              Meteor.call('markers.insert',Position);
            }
        },
        "click [data-action='needle/pickup']": ()=> {
          var marker_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
          pickUp(marker_id);
        },
        "click [data-action='needle/mark']": ()=> {
          var marker_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
          markForPickUp(marker_id);
        }
      });
```

HTML for button:

```
<template name="MapPage">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
    <a style="text-align:center;" class="over_map">
        {{#if currentUser }}
            <button class="needle-btn btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-responsive">Needle</button>
        {{/if}}
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any advice on why the method is executing twice would be much appreciated!
I have tried moving the methods into a separate file, have had them outside of Meteor.isServer, inside, etc.

Thanks!

Edit:
Entire map.js file:

```
import map_style from './map_style.js';
import { Markers } from '../api/methods.js';

Position = null;

function onPositionRecieved(position) {
    console.log(position);
    Position = { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude };
    // center = new google.maps.LatLng(Position);
    // GoogleMaps.maps.map.options.center = center;

}

function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 2
    };
}

function onPositionNotReceived(positionError) {
    console.log(positionError);
    alert(positionError.message);
}

function get_location() {
    var position = {}
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onPositionRecieved,onPositionNotReceived);
    }
}

function checkIsUser() {
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go("/");
  }
}

function pickUp(marker_id) {
  Meteor.call('markers.pickup',marker_id);
  console.log("Needle picked up. ID: " + String(marker_id));
}

function markForPickUp(marker_id) {
  Meteor.call('markers.markforpickup',marker_id);
}



if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.MapPage.onCreated(function() {

    checkIsUser();
    get_location();

    console.log("Click watch int.");

    Template.MapPage.events({
        'click .needle-btn': ()=> {
            if (Position == null) {
              alert("Location services not enabled :(")
            }

            if (Meteor.userId() != null) {
              console.log("inserting");
              Meteor.call('markers.insert',Position);
            }
        },
        "click [data-action='needle/pickup']": ()=> {
          var marker_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
          pickUp(marker_id);
        },
        "click [data-action='needle/mark']": ()=> {
          var marker_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
          markForPickUp(marker_id);
        }
      });


    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {

      var markers = {};

      Markers.find().observe({
        added: function (document) {
          console.log(document);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(document.position.lat, document.position.lng),
            map: map.instance,
            id: document._id,
            icon: pinSymbol('red')
          });

          if (document.hasOwnProperty('icon')) {
            marker.setIcon(document.icon);
          }

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: `<div class="infodiv">
                        <h1>Picked up?</h1>
                        <div class="btn-group special" role="group">
                          <button id="` + marker.id + `" data-action="needle/pickup" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-success"><h2 id="` + marker.id + `">Yes</h2></button>
                          <button id="` + marker.id + `" data-action="needle/mark" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger"><h2 id="` + marker.id + `">No</h2></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      `
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            Meteor.call('markers.updatelocation', marker.id, event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            console.log("Marker Clicked");
          });

          markers[document._id] = marker;
        },
        changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
          markers[newDocument._id].setPosition({ lat: newDocument.position.lat, lng: newDocument.position.lng });
          if (newDocument.icon != null) {
            markers[newDocument._id].setIcon(newDocument.icon);
          }
        },
        removed: function (oldDocument) {
          markers[oldDocument._id].setMap(null);
          google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(markers[oldDocument._id]);
          delete markers[oldDocument._id];
        }
      });
    });
  });

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load({key: 'KEYOMITTED'});
  });

  Template.MapPage.helpers({
    mapOptions: function() {
      if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
        return {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.803187, -124.160748),
          zoom: 16,
          styles: map_style

        };
      }
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'markers.insert'(position) {

      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }
      console.log("Woohoo");
       if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Markers.insert({
          position: position,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          owner: Meteor.userId(),
          username: Meteor.user().profile.name,
        });
       }
    },

    'markers.remove'(markerId) {
      check(markerId, String);

      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }

      Markers.remove(markerId);
    },

    'markers.pickup'(markerId) {
      check(markerId, String);

      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }

      Markers.update(markerId,
       { $set: { icon: pinSymbol('green') }},
       function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
        }
      );

    },

    'markers.markforpickup' (markerId) {
      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }

      if (markerId != null) {
        Markers.update(markerId,
          { $set: { icon: pinSymbol('red') }},
          function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
          }
        );
        console.log("Needle marked for pickup. ID: " + String(markerId));
      }
      else {
        console.log("Null needle ID!");
      }
    },

    'markers.updatelocation'(markerId,lat_in,lng_in) {
      // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
      }
      console.log(markerId,lat_in,lng_in);

      Markers.update(markerId,
       { $set: { position: { lat: lat_in, lng: lng_in } }},
       function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
          }
        );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you add any HTML that includes the buttons and surrounding code to your question?

Comment: @chazsolo Added the template and rest of the code for the page.

Comment: Where is the MapPage template being rendered? Any chance it's being generated twice?

Comment: @KyleBachan Map page is rendered by the router: `Router.route('/map', function () {
  this.render('MapPage');
}, {
  name: 'MapPage'
});`

Comment: Gotcha. Can you post a link to a github repo?

Comment: @KyleBachan Sure thing, thanks for taking a look!
https://github.com/ConnorCallison/Needler

Comment: Ok so this is weird but I ran your code, and it only actually triggers once for me.

Comment: @KyleBachan Exactly! It only happens sometimes which is really frustrating. I have a galaxy deployment here: https://needler.meteorapp.com if you scroll over to the northern CA area you will see the two markers from one button press. I'm beginning to wonder if it has something to do with a chrome plugin I'm using. Also, try it while inspecting element and changing the device to one of the mobile phones, it will behave differently for me sometimes like that.

Comment: Hmm, so weird. I'll try it out when I get home tonight and see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: @KyleBachan Sweet. Thanks again for your help!